# how can I share components in two projects in NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, components

I don't know which is best option to share component ReactJs in my particular case, I have two application in NextJs, one is e-commerce and another is a manager portal for this e-commerce.

In first app (e-commerce) I have UI Components (buttons, fields, headings, texts, etc), and I want to use these components in the other project, I been thinkings uncouple UI Components and create a new repo, and this repo sharing to both project.

I don't know if this is right thing to do that?

Can I create this repo (UI) in NextJs for use benefits of them? with NextJs is very easy to use Typescript, EsLint, also NextJs include base template PostCSS, and with nextjs almost hardly need config anything.

What do you recommend?

Can I use Next Js only to create repository of components? is recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a component library.

[Component library using bit](https://blog.bitsrc.io/building-a-react-component-library-d92a2da8eab9)

[Create react library](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library)

Here's an article with your question as the header: https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-share-react-components-between-nextjs-projects-c0857bbc1fcb

Comment: but, can I create library in NextJs?

Comment: When you are thinking of component libraries, they are just components which can be USED in any react application. NextJS is a way to assemble a react application. You still have to write components. If you want to use NextJS components in your library, you can do that too by adding NextJS as a dependency of your component library. But I would not recommend that. Try to visualise and seperate React specific code from NextJS.